# How to limit facebook apprequests to certain users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a *iOS mobile application* that needs to send out an app request to a user's friends. From here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk and here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#mfs it appears I am able to suggest the users that this app requesst gets sent to. I am making the call like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Check out this awesome app", @"message",
                        @"1xxx4,10xxxx0,", @"suggestions",
                        nil];
[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
            andParams:params 
          andDelegate:nil];
```

However, once the multi-friend request dialog is presented, I am still able to type in a friends name, even if it was not part of the "suggestions". How do I make this restriction?

The end goal is to restrict that list to facebook friends who are not users of this app. The docs also mention a "filters" parameter, but i have not got that to work.

Ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't only allowing users to send invites to people NOT using the app increase the rate at which your invites are ignored, deleted and reported as spam? why not just simplify things and let the users send the invites to whomever they think is most likely to enjoy them

Comment: The idea is to invite people to use the app. Is there a better mechanism for this? Also, my thought is that if a user is picking who she wants to send invites to, it would be to people she knows.